# How to remove certain features that have a low completeness rate in a Data frame(Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data Frame with more than 450 variables and more than 500 000 rows. However, some variables have null values ​​over 90%. I would like to delete features with more than > 90% empty rows.

I made my description of my variables:

Data Frame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':list('abcdefghij'),
     'B':[4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
     'C':[7,8,np.nan,4,2,3,6,5, 4, 6],
     'D':[1,3,5,np.nan,1,0,10,7, np.nan, 5],
     'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4,7,3, 5, 9],
     'F':list('aaabbbckfr'),
     'G':[np.nan,8,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

print(df)
   A    B  C   D  E  F    G
0  a  4.0  7   1  5  a  NaN
1  b  NaN  8   3  3  a  8.0
2  c  NaN  NaN 5  6  a  NaN
3  d  NaN  4  NaN 9  b  NaN
4  e  NaN  2   1  2  b  NaN
5  f  NaN  3   0  4  b  NaN
6  g  NaN  6  10  7  c  NaN
7  h  NaN  5   7  3  k  NaN
8  i  NaN  4  NaN 5  f  NaN
9  j  NaN  6   5  9  r  NaN
```

Describe:

```
desc = df.describe(include = 'all')
d1 = desc.loc['varType'] = desc.dtypes
d3 = desc.loc['rowsNull'] = df.isnull().sum()
d4 = desc.loc['%rowsNull'] = round((d3/len(df))*100, 2)

print(desc)
                A        B        C        D        E       F        G
count          10        1       10       10       10      10        1
unique         10      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       6      NaN
top             i      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       b      NaN
freq            1      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       3      NaN
mean          NaN        4      5.4      4.3      5.3     NaN        8
std           NaN      NaN  2.22111  3.16403  2.45176     NaN      NaN
min           NaN        4        2        0        2     NaN        8
25%           NaN        4        4      1.5     3.25     NaN        8
50%           NaN        4      5.5      4.5        5     NaN        8
75%           NaN        4     6.75      6.5     6.75     NaN        8
max           NaN        4        9       10        9     NaN        8
varType    object  float64  float64  float64  float64  object  float64
rowsNull        0        9        1        2        0       0        9
%rowsNull       0       90       10       20        0       0       90
```

In this exemple we have juste 2 features to delete 'B' and 'G'.
But in my case i find 40 variables whose '%rowsNull' greater than > 90%, how should i do not take into account these variables in my modeling?

I have no idea how to do this.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First compare missing values and then get `mean` (it working because `True`s are processing like `1`s), last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc`, because removing columns:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.isnull().mean() <.9]
print (df)
   A    C     D  E  F
0  a  7.0   1.0  5  a
1  b  8.0   3.0  3  a
2  c  NaN   5.0  6  a
3  d  4.0   NaN  9  b
4  e  2.0   1.0  2  b
5  f  3.0   0.0  4  b
6  g  6.0  10.0  7  c
7  h  5.0   7.0  3  k
8  i  4.0   NaN  5  f
9  j  6.0   5.0  9  r
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.isnull().mean())
A    0.0
B    0.9
C    0.1
D    0.2
E    0.0
F    0.0
G    0.9
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is interesting, never thought of using mean for this

Answer (score 1):

You can find columns with more than 90% null values and drop

```
cols_to_drop = df.columns[df.isnull().sum()/len(df) >= .90]
df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis = 1, inplace = True)


    A   C   D   E   F
0   a   7.0 1.0 5   a
1   b   8.0 3.0 3   a
2   c   NaN 5.0 6   a
3   d   4.0 NaN 9   b
4   e   2.0 1.0 2   b
5   f   3.0 0.0 4   b
6   g   6.0 10.0    7   
7   h   5.0 7.0 3   k
8   i   4.0 NaN 5   f
9   j   6.0 5.0 9   r
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you could do something like

```
keepCols = desc.columns[desc.loc['%rowsNull'] < 90]
df = df[keepCols]
```